# android listview

Tags: android, listview

I have created one list view.. it is having 5 items...

Now I want split the list items...

when user clickon the first listitem or focus on first item then immediately it has to show  followed some text views or other things..but it has to show same list..

and agian same when he clickon or focus on the second item that first item has to be close and second item has to act some thing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use the standard ListView in your case, because in the standard ListView, the View of each row has to be one TextView.
In your case, you need it to be at least two TextViews (The standard Text, and the one that's gonna show up onClick/onFocus).

You have to create your custom ListAdapter, and override the getView() function.
Here is a code snippet that shows how to do it properly:
[Custom Adapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html)

In the getView(), you have to inflate the XML file that describes your List Row, and return it.
In your case, I believe your XML file should contain 2 TextViews, one visible and one invisible.

Then, to handle the clicks, you can set a onItemClickListener on your ListView in your Activity class.
The best way may be to have your Activity class implementing onItemClickListener, and to use this onItemClickListener to handle those.
In the onClick() function, you just have to set the Visibility of your hidden TextView to VISIBLE.

Comment: i HAVE DONE WAHT U SUGESTEDAbstMainActivity take care of LayoutInflater mInflater;getCount();Object getItem(int position);getItemId(int position);holder = new ViewHolder();holder.text = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.TextView01); holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.TextView02); convertView.setTag(holder); } else { holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); }holder.text.setText(symbol[position]); holder.text2.setText(mainMenu[position]); return convertView;

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.main); ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01); l1.setAdapter(new AbstMainActivity(this));

Comment: I dont know  How i have to split list items

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to implement the concept of **"Expandable Listview"**, so that the clicking on one item, it will be expanded with their sub-items.

Refer the android-sdk page of Expandable ListView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

For having an example, check this site: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/05/expandable-lists.html

**`Pls, check the below image, do you want to perform as same ????`**

[image]

**`If you want to do the same, it is already given in the "API-Demos" at Views/Expandable Lists/1. Custom Adapter`**.

Enjoy !!

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        l1.setAdapter(new AbstMainActivity(this));

Comment: AbstMainActivity take care of LayoutInflater mInflater;getCount();Object getItem(int position);getItemId(int position);holder = new ViewHolder();holder.text = (TextView) convertView
.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }holder.text.setText(symbol[position]);
            holder.text2.setText(mainMenu[position]);
            return convertView;

Comment: @a.t.obulreddy better that you update your question without making comments here, and check my updated answer !!

Comment: @a.t.obulreddy have you check the above image? if it fulfills your requirements then you can do it so. you want to do same as the above attached image?

Comment: can i change the Expandable Listview like using LayoutInflater in my own view

Comment: @a.t.obulreddy you may do it, check this example: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/02/expandable-lists-and-check-boxes.html, overthere checkboxes and textviews are there, same way you can also make your own view

Comment: can i change the Text view into some edit boxes .... i want to user may has to enter some data into that boxes and submit in one of the list option in the Expandable list view

Answer (score 0):

You need to build custom rows, and handle showing more text on each row, there is no easy magicall way of doing it, but inflating your own rows, and setting a couple of attributes visibility isnt all that hard either.